# windows folder names encoding

Tags: php, windows, encoding, character-encoding

i have a folder in windows with Arabic name (utf8)
i'm trying to get this name and display it in a browser using php

```
$enc = mb_detect_encoding($folder);
$utf8folder = iconv($enc, "UTF-8", $folder);
echo $utf8folder;
```

or

```
echo $folder;
```

getting ����...

help!

Comment: What happens if you just echo it, and set your page encoding to UTF-8?  What is your doctype declaration, and relevant meta tags?

Comment: Can you show us your actual doctype declaration and meta tags?  Also, what headers are being sent?

Comment: i'm displaying on an html page with meta: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> so it is already utf-8

Answer (score 1):

Add this as the first line of your php script and try:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Comment: i'm displaying on an html page with meta:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
so it is already utf-8

Comment: @user1576848, Did you even try his suggestion?

Comment: what does $enc say the encoding is?

Comment: @user1576848, Can you provide a link to this page?

Comment: @Brad.. actually it's localhost... no online page

Comment: @user1576848: If it is already UTF encoded, you do not need to do an `iconv()` again. Instead of $folder being the folder name that you fetch, can you just assign a UTF string directly into it (something like الترجمة من) and see if it prints out correctly?

Comment: @Raidenace.. with or without `iconv()` it's not printing correctly..
and it prints 'الترجمة' correctly...
the code exactly is `echo $folder; echo 'الترجمة'`

Comment: @user1576848: are you talking about the folder name, or the string directly assigned. If you are talking about the string directly assigned, then you have issues with the other part of the page (html et al), because I can print it correctly in my browser. Next you would need to check encoding settings in your browser options itself

Comment: @Raidenace.. i'm getting the folder name by this code:
`$dh = @opendir( $path );
$folder = readdir( $dh );`
where $path is the path to $folder's parent..

i'm talking about the real name of the folder which you can see it in windows explorer... like مجلد جديد for example...